# Databinding Image Source at Windows Phone

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone

I have datatable with byte[] column.
On app page I iterate through rows and bind column data to SourceProperty

```
for (i = 0;..) {
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Width = 100;
    img.Height = 100;
    Binding bnd = new Binding("Fields[" + i + "].Blob"); // Blob column
    bnd.Converter = new ByteToImageConverter();
    img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, bnd);
}
```

Near every image I have button that calls `CameraCaptureTask camTask`.

Before `camtask.Show()` I assign current Image to global pointer `_imgCurrent = img`

```
camtask.Completed += (s, e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult != TaskResult.OK) return;
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    _imgCurrent.Source = bmp;
    _imgCurrent.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, bmp);
}
```

But in that case DataContext don't update. I suppose that I need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? I need to inherit Image from that interface or I can trigger it in time of Source update?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at Binding creation: I forgot about `Mode=TwoWay`.